# How to change the part of text format (color,sizebold italic) inside the string?

Tags: java, android, string, text-formatting

Here is my code. I want to change the format of the text partially inside the string.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    String stuff[] = {

"this has to be  the bold part   this has to be normal part",
"this part of text has to be green      this part of text has to be blue",
"this is number 3 bold",
```

}

Comment: is this string static or dynamic?

Comment: create mutltiple TextViews, and split your string into them. Then you can set style for each TextView apart

Comment: @MishaBhardwaj both in dynamic and static.

Comment: @VeaceslavGaidarji Thanx but the text has to be in single text view.I I want the first part format to be different than the second part but inside " the first part the second part",.

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTML fomatting:

`textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>test</b> test"));`

Comment: this method would be too complicate to deal with lots of text as Parts are merged into one sentences and in this project I have numerous text groups to deal.

Comment: Why would it be too complicated? This seems like the easiest way of adding formats to text, no matter how much text you have. You can still write some kind of wrapper class that outputs a HTML formatted string when you set certain styles. Then you only have to concatenate those strings and set it to the TextView.

Comment: Thanks again  I try to deal with it .

Answer (score 0):

You must use `SpannableStringBuilder` like below:

```
    String finalText = stuff[0]+ " " + stuff[1] + " " + stuff[2];
    int first = stuff[0].length() + 1;
    int second = stuff[1].length() + 1;
    int end = finalText.length();

    SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(finalText);
    stringBuilder.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", normalFont), 0, first, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    stringBuilder.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", boldFont), first, first + second, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    stringBuilder.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", normalFont), first + second, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

    textView.setText(stringBuilder);
```